# Master bath faucet leaks when using other showers or when running dishwasher

Tags: leak, faucet, bathtub

I have a master bathroom pretty much next to a second bathroom upstairs. Lately I noticed that when the 2nd bathroom shower is being used the master bathtub faucet leaks. I guess the same thing is happening when the dishwasher is running as well. What could be causing this or what can I do to stop it from happening?

Comment: did it start leaking when the 2nd bathroom was used (leaking all the way until the 2nd bathroom stop)? or is it only start leaking when right after 2nd BR stop?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an anti-scald mixing valve then it sounds like the seal (gasket) inside the bathtub faucet's cartridge could be compromised.

When the water pressure is full force (no other faucet diverting pressure) then the gasket is being sealed by the water pressure but as soon as a tap is opened then it alleviates enough pressure for the tub valve to fail.

You probably need to replace the cartridge in the tub faucet.

Even if it's not an anti-scald valve you need to investigate the gaskets inside the faucet.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you, I appreciate it.